# Validate to check uploaded file is pdf

Tags: java

How to validate if the file uploaded is PDF only? not only by extension(.pdf) but also with the content.If someone change the extension of any other file to pdf file then it should fail while uploading.

Comment: i have to put a validation in an application  while pdf file is being uploaded

Comment: You may need to read Adobe Reader's documentation to see how it validates PDF

Comment: Are you asking for a full scale validation (that the file is a proper PDF respecting the specification from start to finish), or just a check that says : "this looks like a PDF and can definitely not be a Word Document or a JPEG" ?

Answer (score 4):

There are many way to validate PDF file. I used itext for check pdf is corrupted or not.

```
try {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);

        PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1);

        LOGGER.info("pdfFileValidator ==> Exit");
        return true;
    } catch (InvalidPdfException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("pdfFileValidator ==> Exit. Error ==> " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

If file is not PDF or file is corrupted than it will throw *InvalidPDFException*.
For above example you need itext library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Tika for this, available here. http://tika.apache.org/

You can also find a practical example here:  https://dzone.com/articles/determining-file-types-java

Comment: If PDF is the only format to check for, then adding the Tika JAR might be overkill If I remember correctly, Tika checks file types by looking at a list of magic numbers, which for PDF, is the first 4 bytes `%PDF`. Only in certain special cases like legacy MS Office formats (which are all OLE components) or in case of compression, does it attempt a detailed parsing of the contents. But as I remeber it, for recognizing a PDF, simply checking the 4 bytes is the only thing Tika will do.

Comment: Indeed, this is overkill. There is probably a "lighter" solution out there, more easy to put into place.

Answer (score 2):

There are many validation libraries that you can use in order to validate if a file is PDF compliant. For instance, you can use - [veradpf](https://verapdf.org/) or [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). Of course you can use any other library that would do the work for you. As it was already mentioned, [tika](https://tika.apache.org/) is another library that can read file metadata and tell you what the file is.

As an example (a bare one), you can do something with `pdfbox`. Also keep in mind that this **will** validate if the file is PDF/A compliant.

```java
boolean validateImpl(File file) {

    PreflightDocument document = new PreflightParser(file).getPreflightDocument();

    try {
        document.validate();
        ValidationResult validationResult = document.getResult();

        if (validationResult.isValid()) {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
       // Error validating
    }
    return false;
}
```

or with Tika, you can do something like

```java
public ContentType tikaDetect(File file) {

    Tika tika = new Tika();

    String detectedType = tika.detect(file);
}
```